# Extract day of the week from column in dataframe and put in another column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dayofweek

```
# Give day of the week
def DOW(df):
    DOW = pd.Series(datetime.datetime.strptime(df['indx'],'%Y%m%d').strftime('%A'))
    df = df.join(DOW)
    return df
```

I am calling this function from another script as where d is my dataframe which I pass to function DOW

```
 d = TA.DOW(d)
```

It throws the error . what can be solution for same

```
DOW=pd.Series(datetime.datetime.strptime(df['indx'],'%Y%m%d').strftime('%A'))
TypeError: must be string, not Series
```

Comment: You can just call `dt.dayofweek` or `dt.strftime('%A')` on that column if the dtype is already datetime so `df['indx'].dt.strftime('%A')` should work

Comment: The error is self explanatory also, you're trying to pass a `Series` in other words the entire column to a function that takes a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first convert column `indx` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) as mentioned [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497782/extract-day-of-the-week-from-column-in-dataframe-and-put-in-another-column/36497886#comment60602948_36497782):

```
print df
       indx  Value
0  20020101   3.00
1  20020102   3.50
2  20020103   3.30
3  20100101   4.96
4  20100102   4.98

df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['indx'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%A') 
print df
       indx  Value        new
0  20020101   3.00    Tuesday
1  20020102   3.50  Wednesday
2  20020103   3.30   Thursday
3  20100101   4.96     Friday
4  20100102   4.98   Saturday
```